# What metaprogramming functionality does Mirah offer?

Tags: mirah

The Mirah home page says

> Mirah supports various mechanisms for compile-time metaprogramming and macros. Much of the “open class” feel of dynamic languages is possible in Mirah.

But I'm unable to find any specifics.  Does anyone have further information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mirah supports compile time macros. With them, you can define functions that are run at compile time that modify the syntax tree. This allows you to simplify some of the common patterns you see in Java into ones more like those found in Ruby.

For example, `times` is implemented as a macro--though it's currently written in Ruby, not Mirah.

You can use it like this

```
5.times do |i|
  puts i
end
```

to print out the numbers 0-4

in Java it would look something like

```
for(int i=0;i < 5; i++) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

You can of course define your own macros by using the `macro def` macro. For example, say I want to use the common logger4j pattern of checking whether debug is enabled before constructing the debug string. With a macro, I could make the check implicit doing something like this:

```
  macro def debug debug_input
    quote do
      if logger.debugEnabled
        logger.debug `debug_input`
      end
    end
  end
```

which I could call like this

```
debug "something low level is going on: " + gimme_all_the_bytes_as_a_string
```

what's going on there is I'm creating a piece of syntax tree with the `quote do ... end` and dropping the `"something low level is going on: " + gimme_all_the_bytes_as_a_string` expression into it using the ``s which in Mirah macro quote blocks, unquote the syntax tree node within them.

There currently aren't too many resources about how Mirah works, but you can look at the [example code](https://github.com/mirah/mirah/tree/master/examples) on Github. If you have more questions feel free to send an email to the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mirah).

Comment: great answer, thank you!  is this mirah's approach to monkey patching?

Comment: not really, there is a way to add extension methods, `times` being a good example, but a way to override methods doesn't exist as far as I know. Not that that will always be the case.